# SSRS could not create a list of fields for procedure

Tags: reporting-services, parameters

I'm  Using Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services to generate the business reports visual studio.

When i'm adding dataset with stored procedure, im getting this error:

Could not create a list of fields for the query.
 Verify that you can connect to the data source and that your query syntax is correct.

**ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'PROCEDURE_NAME'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored**

stored procedure is simple select :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE [PROCEDURE_NAME](L_CURSOR out SYS_REFCURSOR)
as
Begin
 open L_CURSOR for
 SELECT [columnname] FROM
[tablename]  
End;
```

Configuration:

```
on visual studio 2013. 
DB: Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.4.0 - 64bi
Visual Studio Installed Products:
```

..
    Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio Copyright (c) 2005, 2014
    SQL Server Data Tools 12.0.30919.1 ...

Comment: I am not sure whether the `Out` type parameter is allowed in `SSRS ` or not ? You might want to check that out?

Comment: Thank you for answer,yes, it is allowed. I think  problem is about providers.. .Net Framework Data Provider for Oracle..

Comment: Here is the link on how to connect `Oracle` to `SSRS` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/dd220591.aspx#Connection

Comment: Dataset is still connected database. when im select query type "text" at Dataset Properties and "select * from [table_name]",  works.  But i cant call stored procedure.

Comment: Take a look at this link this might help you http://www.joellipman.com/articles/microsoft/sql-server/ssrs/559-returning-oracle-stored-procedure-resultset-in-ssrs.html

Comment: Ok. The issue is with your procedure is that you are using `AS`  in place of `IS`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is of inside question. It is about provider.
Change my provider ODTwithODAC for 10g (my database version). And problem resolved.

Thank you for your helps,
Regards,
A